# Compiling C++ with SWIG for javascript on Mac OS X

Tags: javascript, c++, swig, v8

I am trying to compile SWIG output file for javascript, but it fails to compile and gives as an output a list of errors. Could someone tell me how to include V8 libraries for this purpose? The output file was generated with this command

```
swig -c++ -javascript -v8 example.i
```

Some Error from the list:

```
example_wrap.cxx:769:9: error: no type named 'Arguments' in namespace 'v8'; did
you mean 'v8::internal::Arguments'?typedef v8::Arguments SwigV8Arguments;
```

The command which used to compile:

```
gcc -c example_wrap.cxx -Iv8/include
```

All samples I have taken [from the official website of SWIG](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Javascript.html)

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the description, please take a look again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

v8's version should be provided when generating wrapper class.

```
brew install swig
brew install v8
swig -c++ -javascript -v8 -DV8_VERSION=0x041027 example.i
gcc -c example_wrap.cxx -I /usr/local/Cellar/v8/4.1.0.27/include/
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. This was proper answer, just in my case it was necessary to put this snippet in the end of this command.

-std=c++0x

But I am wondering how it would be possible to compile this file for Android platform (not for JNI, but for javascript calls)